# Modelling Proton Beams using Numerical Methods

Tags: computational-physics, protons

I'm attempting to **model proton beams**/proton therapy using numerical models in MATLAB.

I'm having trouble tracking down the correct master equations to use to model beam energy (60-250MeV range) against depth in media, Bragg peak distribution, and dose.

Whatever I find has to be broken down into **differential equations** to be used in **Runge-Kutta** or similar numerical methods in MATLAB.

So far I have a few equations which look viable, but I'm having trouble figuring out which ones to unpack and apply to my problem.

The main resource I'm looking at is here:

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-9155/60/8/R155

It deals with a whole range of components

- Energy-loss rate
- Range
- Energy and Range Straggling
- Multiple Coulomb Scattering
- etc

My understanding is that I could use the Bortfeld (1997) analytical solution to calculate the Bragg Curve

[image: Bortfeld Equation]

Other than that I'm not really understanding the relationship between energy-loss rate, range, and range straggling and how I use those to model a proton beam.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The [*Particle Data Book*](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/contents_sports.html) chapter on the "Passage of particles through matter" is always a good starting place. But ... for serious work you are almost certainly better off using a well tuned existing code (of which there are many both general purpose and specific to radiation thearpy). If this is for an exercise, that's a whole different matter, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome resource! I’m doing this for a university project. I’m able to use some other code as long as a understand it and implement it in my own way, customise it and cite the sources used. However I was looking for resources on github which I only signed up for the other day and couldn’t find anything related to proton beams or heavy charged particle simulations. Do you have any any suggested resources I could search for example code?

Comment: The problem is that well-tuned professional codes tend to be complex and subtle. They aren't easy to use as roadmaps for learning projects. For instance Geant breaks the many physical effects into multiple classes of interactions, modeled using different process; expects the user to register an appropriate set of processes to model the things that they care about; then uses the registration list to decide what to calculate on each time-step. Not an easy thing to follow and too baroque for a project.

Comment: This is basically the same reason that various teaching operating systems exist: to give learners a model system that does all the necessary stuff, but does it as comprehensible as possible rather than as well as possible. And I don't know of example particle transport codes for learning from. My numeric physics professor has a set of assignment to help us build our toy models, but didn't provide an example code.